# Confused why function isn't printing address

Tags: c, printf

Could anyone explain why running the following code prints only the newline character?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int x = 12;
    char *s = (char *) &x;
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Since we're casting `&x` as a string, shouldn't what is printed be the string representation of the address of `x` (presumably some hexadecimal memory address)?

Comment: "shouldn't what is printed be the string representation of the address of x..." - No. it shouldn't. Use `%p` for printing address values.

Answer (score 6):

Your code exhibits [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you are trying to print an int's address using `%s`.

`%s` in `printf` family of function is used to print `\0` terminated character array or `c-type strings`

From C11 specs, **7.21.6.1 The fprintf function**

> (8) %s: If no l length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to
>   the initial element of an array of character type.<sup>280)</sup> Characters from
>   the array are written up to (but not including) the terminating null
>   character. If the precision is specified, no more than that many bytes
>   are written. If the precision is not specified or is greater than the
>   size of the array, the array shall contain a null character.
>   
> <sup>280) No special provisions are made for multibyte characters</sup>

And later

> (9) If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.<sup>282)</sup> If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.
>   
> <sup>282) See ‘‘future library directions’’ (7.31.11).</sup>

---

One of the many possibilities that may happen is: (I am assuming a lot about the implementation here)

your int appears in memory as following 4 bytes

```
s (not guaranteed to hold the same address)
s   s+1 s+2 s+3 s+4
+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 12|
+---+---+---+---+
&x
```

or

```
s (not guaranteed to hold the same address)
s   s+1 s+2 s+3 s+4
+---+---+---+---+
| 12| 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+
&x
```

Where 12 or form-feed or `\f` is a non-printable ascii character and may not print anything on the screen.

When you reinterpret it as `char *` and print, an empty string is printed followed by the newline. Although this is not guaranteed and anything may happen from crashing to printing indefinitely (or even worse).

Correct way to print an `int` is:

```
printf("%d\n", x);
```

Comment: It's much more probable that topic starter is on x86 so he has LSB order. Then printing is always interpreted as "\f\0\0\0" followed by "\n". And the actual question was about printing pointer value as @Joachim answered.

Comment: @user4419802 How is 12 translated to `\f`?

Comment: **One of the many possibilities that may happen is**... Anyways character `12` (Form-feed in ascii) is non-printable and give its own surprises usually by printing nothing.

Comment: @Eregrith 12 is `\f` or formfeed

Comment: @Eregrith Usually \f is form feed ASCII 12. But it's probably not visible on the screen.

Answer (score 6):

A string is a sequence of characters, terminated by the special character `'\0'`. When you print a string using the `"%s"` format, the `printf` function takes the address as a base address and prints characters from that base until it finds the terminator. If the "string" isn't actually a string, you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to print an *address* you should use the `"%p"` format:

```
printf("Address of variable x is %p\n", (void *) &p);
```